# SSO and IdentityServer with services that expect SAML and JWT

Tags: .net-core, single-sign-on, jwt, saml, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 with OpenID Connect and OAuth2.

I need to enable SSO with some legacy services that support SAML.

Can someone explain (or point me to a good article) explaining how this could be achieved?

Would I need to request a SAML token from IdentityServer for my JWT token that I can pass to the legacy service? Or could I embed the SAML token into the JWT ID token which can then be extracted and passed to the legacy service?

Comment: Hey @DaImTo thanks for the response. But that link is for "Protecting an API using Passwords". I'm not sure what that has to do with supporting SSO between a service that expects a SAML token and a service that expects a JWT?

Comment: Looking for similar solution here. Essentially can someone point out the best way to generate a SAML token in IdentityServer given it is provided with a valid and trusted JWT token for exchange?

Answer (score 4):

You need a SAML2P plugin for IdentityServer4, there's an experimental version at https://leastprivilege.com/2017/10/13/saml2p-identity-provider-support-for-identityserver4/

Comment: hi @Anders, i want to enable SSO across a number of websites and native tablet apps. The legacy websites only support SAML and the newer native apps support OpenId Connect. Therefore, I can't pass the JWT from the native app to the website or the SAML token from the website to the native app. I've read the available material on SAML2P and I can't see any documentation discussing this use case. Is SAML2P what I need here?

Comment: hi @Anders just thought I would see if you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As @Anders says, there is a beta version developed by Rock Solid Knowledge.

This only handles client-side SAML at the moment.

What is your exact use case?

Comment: hi @nzpcmad, i want to enable SSO across a number of websites and native tablet apps. The legacy websites only support SAML and the newer native apps support OpenId Connect. Therefore, I can't pass the JWT from the native app to the website or the SAML token from the website to the native app.

Comment: hi @nzpcmad just thought I would see if you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you document your use cases e.g. App. --> OIDC --> ADFS or App. --> SAML -> ADFS or App --> ADFS --> SAML --> another IDP.